# Alternate method for android sdk installation

Tags: android

Is there an offline installation package for android? I installed the basic ADT and every time I try to access the site and download the APIs and other tools using sdk manager, there is an access problem(I dont even have the adb.exe). I found that downloading using sdk manager is out of option for me due to company policies. Is there some simple exe installation that would help me start my work? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for offline download here - 
http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html